# ERROR 1005 (HY000): Can't create table db.#sql-5471_137' (errno: 121)

Tags: mysql, constraints

```
 alter table xxx
 add CONSTRAINT `FK_usagehistory_4` FOREIGN KEY (`AuthID`) REFERENCES `licenseattributes` (`AuthID`),
 add CONSTRAINT `FK_usage_5` FOREIGN KEY (`SaaSClientIdentifierID`) REFERENCES `saasclientnodes` (`SaaSClientIdentifierID`),
 add CONSTRAINT `FK_usage_6` FOREIGN KEY (`SaaSServerIdentifierID`) REFERENCES `saasservernodes` (`SaaSServerIdentifierID`),
 add CONSTRAINT `FK_usage_9` FOREIGN KEY (`TenantID`) REFERENCES `tenant` (`TenantID`);
```

I am getting ERROR **"1005 (HY000): Can't create table 'db.#sql-5471_137' (errno: 121)"**  while runng above command .

Comment: CREATE TABLE `usagehistory_new` (
  `TenantID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `AuthID` int(10) unsigned NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SessionID` varchar(255) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `SaaSClientIdentifierID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL,
  `SaaSServerIdentifierID` int(10) unsigned DEFAULT NULL);

Comment: Then I added PK as alter table xxx
    ->   add PRIMARY KEY (`SessionID`,`TenantID`),
    ->   add KEY `FK_usage_5` (`SaaSClientIdentifierID`),
    ->   add KEY `FK_usage_6` (`SaaSServerIdentifierID`),
    ->   add KEY `FK_usage_9` (`TenantID`),
    ->   add KEY `FK_usagehistory_4` (`AuthID`);

Comment: this problem has been solved. I have changed fk name as its was same as pk. That's why I was getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

The error seems to be because you are creating a a foreign key constraint and you need to have a usable index in referencing table and in the referenced table to do so in MySQL. Probably the index on the referenced table would be missing which you have to create by yourself. The index on the referencing table will be created automatically, so no need to create that.

Comment: What I need to do here and how?

Answer (score 0):

This problem had been solved. I had changed fk name as its was same as pk. That's why I was getting this error.